# (dygraph)x-axis label generated only at the point with the value

Tags: axis, point, x-axis

I have a question about the dygraph. I want to have the x-axis label generated only at the point with the value. Is it possible? [image: line graph]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.